# iphone Image doesn't appear after downloading

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am building a simple application to show images.

I send the image url, and it should be downloading.

This is my code:

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView * imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage * image;
@end

@implementation ImageViewController

-(void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{
    _imageURL = imageURL;
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
}

-(UIImageView*)imageView{
    if(!_imageView)
        return [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    return _imageView;
}


-(UIImage*)image{
    return self.imageView.image;
}

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image{
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self.imageView sizeToFit];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    NSLog(@"Image Url = %@", self.imageURL);
}

@end
```

I call it like this:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ImageViewController class]]){
        ImageViewController* ivc = (ImageViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        ivc.imageURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-5s/gallery/a/images/download/%@.jpg", segue.identifier]];
```

#### I am 100% sure that the passed url is correct because I already check that through debugging

The image is absolutely being downloaded because its size is large and the screen is blocking while downloading it.

The problem is the that imageView doesn't show it after finishing downloading.

Could u help me please?

#### Edit

The header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSURL* imageURL;
@end
```

This is all my code, so you can test it if you want.

#### Edit2

I have a scroll view, maybe that is the problem ?
Please check the image

[image]

Comment: Can u give the exact url?

Comment: @SmritiYadav http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-5s/gallery/a/images/download/photo_1.jpg

Comment: as you are passing url to another view controller, just try to pass NSString and then try to convert it in URL just before you code for setting image from this URL..

Comment: @SmritiYadav I edited the question and gave you the header file, you can test it in your environment if you want.

Comment: You'd better adjust imageView's frame manually according to the image's size. Check imageView's frame after sending it sizeToFit.

Comment: @Ashutosh the url is completely correct, I already made the debug in the `viewdidload` and I can see it correct

Comment: @KudoCC yes that is what I am doing now. please check this line ` [self.imageView sizeToFit];`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Check its frame after sending it sizeToFit method.

Comment: @KudoCC sorry I didn't get you. How could I do that? I am new to IOS development

Comment: you have an issue in the getter of the `imageView`, you are not initialising the attribute, replace the line: `return [[UIImageView alloc]init];` by `_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];`

Comment: Create UIImageView properly if you want to do it programmatically or just use storyboard or xib.

Comment: @tkanzakic you the one man, yes you right. write an answer to accept it.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli glad to help you, I have written my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in the getter of the `imageView` property. You are not initialising the attribute, but returning a different object each time. Replace the line:

```
return [[UIImageView alloc]init];
```

by

```
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Please try to edit your code as following it is working for me, in your case problem may be because you are passing url from different view controller that you are :

```
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-5s/gallery/a/images/download/photo_1.jpg"]]]];
```

You can check from attached screen shot..

Comment: I am trying yoru solution

Comment: Sorry  tkanzakic helped me in his comment. +1 to your efforts with me

Answer (score 1):

Set the imageView's frame instead of sending sizeToFit method.

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image{
    self.imageView.image = image;
    // [self.imageView sizeToFit];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ;
}
```

Edit :

I see there is a scrollView on 'self.view', so it may block `self.imageView`, try to bring it to front using `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView] ;` if you want it be the topmost of all subView on `self.view`.

Comment: Sorry  tkanzakic helped me in his comment. +1 to your efforts with me

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning you newly created `imageView` to your `_imageView`. So every time it triggers `imageView` method, it returns a new `UIImageView`. try this...

```
- (UIImageView*)imageView
{
    if(!_imageView) {
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        return _imageView;
    }

    return _imageView;
}
```